# Screensharing (Slack, Hangouts) Blank Screen & Cursor On Ubuntu 17.10 (Wayland)

Tags: 17.10, wayland, google-hangouts, slack

I've been using 17.10 with the default Desktop (Gnome/Wayland) for about a week and is running very smoothly except for one thing:

I no longer can share my screen with the Slack Linux app or with Hangouts (in Chrome).
The other party **only sees a black screen and the cursor** moving.

However if **I only share a window (Hangouts) then it works**.

It happens to one of my workmates as well, with a fresh 17.10 install. Used to work perfectly so far with previous Ubuntu versions.

Does anyone know what is the source of the problem and a possible solution/workaround? Or if there's a bug already reported?

**UPDATE:** It seems to be Wayland related as it works on X, ie. when I login to *Ubuntu on Xorg* session.

Comment: The problem is that 17.10 uses wayland instead of x11. At log in, try login with Ubuntu on Xorg.

Comment: Yes it works on X. But I stick to wayland as it's handles my 4K monitor waaay better.